# PHP - PHPGraphLib - Graph with dynamic dimension?

Tags: php

For create a new graph this is the first step :

```
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(650,450);
```

There is same way for having a dinamic dimension of graph like this :

```
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(50%,50%);
```

where 50% is refered to html div container dimension where the img is displayed ?

**CODE REVIEW**

I found this way with javascript :

```
var clientWidth = document.getElementById('main').clientWidth;
$('#main').load('graph.php?width='+clientWidth);
```

and into the graph.php :

```
if (isset($_GET['width'])) { $width = $_GET['width']; }
$graph=new PHPGraphLib($width,450);
```

Comment: see here http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-setup-and-simple-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finalize the graph, with `$graph->createGraph();`

Example

**Create Graph**

```
<?php
    // File: graph.php
    include("phpgraphlib.php");
    $graph = new PHPGraphLib(400,300);
    $data = array("A"=>10, "B"=>20, "C"=>30);
    $graph->addData($data);
    $graph->setTitle("Scores");
    $graph->setTextColor("red");
    $graph->createGraph();
?>
```

**Display Graph**

```
//index.html
<html>
<img src="graph.php" />
</html>
```

[More PHPGraphLib Examples](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/examples)

**Dynamic Image dimensions**

```
<img width="50%" height="20%" src="graph.php" />
```

or wrapped in a fixed-size div-tag, like so:

```
<div style="height:50px; width: 50px">
    <img src="graph.php" style="width:100%; height:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: @jens-andre-kock in this way you stretch the image, i want that the phpgraphlib calculate the right dim of the space for the bars inside a graph

Comment: Ok, but i would not do that. The downside of this approach is, that your server has a lot of images to generate: for every users device size, you detect the value and hand it over to PHP. It wouldn't work for larger systems. But for your use-case it might be good enough. I would suggest to generate one big_graph and a small_graph, then use dynamic width attributes or resizing the image. By doing that a webserver would cache the static files and deliver them fastly. Show the small one first and onclick/onhover the larger one, or lightbox.